# Pressing delete button on a baked form CakePHP results in "The request has been black-holed"

Tags: cakephp

I've baked a CRUD form (cakePHP 2.3) and the index page lists the records with a delete button for each row.

I've added Security and now when I press the delete button I get the black-hole message.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $comment['Comment']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $comment['Comment']['id'])); ?>
```

The above is the default code generated by bake.

I'm also using LoggableBehaviour with the following in AppController::beforeFilter:

```
if (sizeof($this->uses) && $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->attached('Logable')) {
                $this->{$this->modelClass}->setUserData($this->activeUser);
            }
```

The markup is:

```
<td class="actions">
<a href="/myapp/forms/view/1">View</a>          
<a href="/myapp/forms/edit/1">Edit</a>
<form action="/myapp/forms/delete/1" name="post_52fa2ac48ca50395155261" id="post_52fa2ac48ca50395155261" style="display:none;" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="19b320270fb40befed83662913cbd404c4e7b15d" id="Token579420200"/>
  <div style="display:none;">
      <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="4e14eecc0fbdf0accdaab5ced4169b7aa4ab933a%3A" id="TokenFields922800459"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value="" id="TokenUnlocked894635034"/>
   </div>
</form><a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;Are you sure you want to delete # 1?&#039;)) { document.post_52fa2ac48ca50395155261.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
</td>
```

The black-hole error is:

```
Error: The requested address '/myapp/users/delete/76' was not found on this server.
```

Comment: What's the markup that gets generated by your postLink?

Comment: Do you have the list inside a form? You know `postLink` actually creates form around the link and nested forms will fail the security check. If this is not the case what is the type of security error?